# can i use php tags in jsp

Tags: php, jsp

Can I write and use PHP tags in my JSP code .my environment is eclipse luna and tomcat 6. I'm trying to do this thing because in my project I need server-side validation is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Why you do not use Java for that?

Comment: Why you are using both Java and PhP??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is simply No.

Your Java interpreter, which is the thing compiling / processing the code, can't understand PHP. And there's nothing about server-side validation which requires PHP. You can write that kind of logic in any programming language.